# Get list items to appear all on one line

Tags: html, css

Here is my code: http://jsfiddle.net/DFN5y/

As you can see the list items on the right are on the line below. Can anyone please tell me how to remedy this? This is my code:

```
<ul id="nav">
    <li><a href="features.html">Features</a></li>
    <li><a href="pricing.html">Pricing</a></li>
</ul>

<ul id="nav" style="float:right;">
    <li><a href="signup.html">Sign up</a></li>
    <li><a href="login.html">Login</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: @mdesdev : check before giving suggestions.

Comment: Duplicate id's are BAD !

Comment: good point. try adding class instead id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set them inline by making `ul` as `inline-block` element

```
ul {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

but you have two nav's and duplicate id's so look at the example below and try to follow that style in future coding

```
<ul id="nav">
  <li><a href="features.html">Features</a></li>
  <li><a href="pricing.html">Pricing</a></li>
  <li class="right"><a href="signup.html">Sign up</a></li>
  <li class="right"><a href="login.html">Login</a></li>
</ul>


#nav li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-left: 40px;
}
.right{ 
  float: right;
}
```

or you could float them without class e.g.

```
#nav li:nth-child(3),
#nav li:nth-child(4) {
  float: right;
}
```

or even simpler by moving just third element e.g.

```
#nav li:nth-child(n+3) {
  float: right;
}
```

## [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/DFN5y/18/)

Comment: I tried to implement your code here but ran into problems. Can you show me what is wrong, as I think it follows your code instructions. http://jsfiddle.net/NVk2N/

Comment: @Jimmy you have error...it's not `#nav ul li { display: inline-block; }` it's `#nav li { display: inline-block; }`. Your `ul` have `nav` id.

Answer (score 0):

your `#nav` is having 100% width and does not have float, thats why its taking complete space till right edge.

```
#nav {
       float: left;
       padding-left: 100px;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DFN5y/7/)** 
Try:

```
ul li {
    display: block;
    float:left;
    padding-left: 40px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add this to your CSS :

```
ul{ display : inline-block;}
```

And please change the id's of your ùl`tags so that they are different ! Id's should be unique on the page.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DFN5y/15/).

Basically i have changed the original in 4 ways:

- replaced the id `nav`, which had been issued twice, by a class of the same name
- distinguished between the first and the second nav-ul in css formatting
- moved the style dfinitions from the element attribute to the css (somehow the `float` rule  messed up teh alignment)
- all nav-ul being displayed as `inline-block` to assue verticla alignment.

Answer (score 0):

You'd be better off adding them all to the same ul element and then using the `:nth-child` pseudo-selector to add additional padding to the middle elements to create the separation you want.

http://jsfiddle.net/DFN5y/17/

`ul li:nth-child(3){
    padding-left: 20%;
    background: red;`
}